# How to sync folders outside of the usual OneDrive sync folder?

Tags: macos, microsoft, office-365, microsoft-sharepoint, onedrive

I am setting up a OneDrive account on my Mac (macos 10.15.7). The OneDrive local folder is at ~/OneDrive/. I would like to sync other folders as well, *e.g.* ~/Music/, ~/Documents/, etc. OneDrive for Windows 10 has this feature built-in, but of course this is lacking on the macOS version. (OneDrive will not allow your sync directory to be your home directory.) Are there any tricks to get these and other locations to sync here on the Mac?

(FWIW I do have "Premium OneDrive" through my **Microsoft 365 Family** subscription.)

Comment: I find that just creating folders *inside* a cloud folder (EG Documents, Pictures, Music, etc.) and putting your files there instead of the macOS assigned folder works well and avoids the difficulty of moving the hard coded locations elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I just started using Onedrive on Mac recently and was looking for a way to keep using my existing folder structure, hence my late response. I execute the following steps to keep using the `~/Documents` folder and have it synced to my Onedrive. **Please remember: always have a recent backup of all your files before executing the steps below**.

1. Copy the `~/Documents` folder to the OneDrive folder, so it will be
   synced.
2. Empty the original `~/Documents` folder (clean all hidden
   files as well)
3. Make a symbolic link from the original `~/Documents` to the `~/OneDrive/Documents` folder. Be aware: macOS does not let you remove the folder named `~/Documents`. Therefore use the `-F` option to link to an existing (empty) dir:

Example: `ln -F -f -s /Users/<user>/OneDrive/Documents/ /Users/<user>`

Now you can keep using your `~/Documents` folder like you used to while having it synced to Onedrive as well.